# How to get swagger document path generated by grape-swagger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm building a system with rails6 and grape,grape-swagger,swagger_ui_engine.

I can access to swagger ui but it says *"Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:3000/swagger_docs/v1/swagger.yaml"*

[image]

I know I can change the path to swagger.yaml on rails/config/initializers/swagger.rb

```rb
SwaggerUiEngine.configure do |config|
  config.swagger_url = {
    v1: 'swagger.yaml'
  }
end
```

The problem is, I don't know where grape-swagger generates the swagger document. Is there any way to know it? (Before it Do I need to do anything to generate swagger document? I believe grape-swagger generate the doc automatically)

---

This is my routes output, it seems grape-swagger is not generating the swagger document?

```sh
daisuke@78eaf4dac6cc:/rails$ bin/rake routes|grep 'swagger\|Prefix'
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                    swagger_ui_engine        /                                                                                        SwaggerUiEngine::Engine
oauth2_swagger_docs GET  /swagger_docs/oauth2 swagger_ui_engine/swagger_docs#oauth2
       swagger_docs GET  /swagger_docs        swagger_ui_engine/swagger_docs#index
        swagger_doc GET  /swagger_docs/:id    swagger_ui_engine/swagger_docs#show
 single_swagger_doc GET  /single_swagger_doc  swagger_ui_engine/swagger_docs#single_doc
               root GET  /                    swagger_ui_engine/swagger_docs#index
daisuke@78eaf4dac6cc:/rails$
```

And this is my routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'sessions#show'
  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  mount SwaggerUiEngine::Engine, at: '/'
  mount V1::Root => '/api/v1'
end
```

root.rb to mount APIs

```rb
require 'grape'

module V1
  class Root < Grape::API # :nodoc:
    default_format :json

    mount Users::Api => '/users'

    add_swagger_documentation
  end
end
```

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried with swagger.json (not yaml), still the issue existing, swagger-ui says *"Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:3000/swagger_docs/v1/swagger.json"*